# How to check ATQA and SAK of Mifare DESFire smart cards

Tags: smartcard, apdu, mifare, contactless-smartcard, acr122

How to check ATQA and SAK of DESFire cards using ACR122U reader on windows? I know that reader perform REQA and WUPA during card initialization, but when I used, for example, nfctools i get only UID. On smartphone same application give that infirmation.
Also i have use scripting tool for sending APDU(in wrapped mode), and i can get UID (FF CA 00 00 00 or 90 60 00 00 00 -> 90 AF 00 00 00 -> 90 AF 00 00 00 APDUs) and ATS (FF CA 01 00 00 APDU) but really don't know how to get ATQA and SAK for identification card type and parameters. I've tryed send 26 -> 52 -> 93(90 26 00 00 00 etc.) but get only 90 1C answer that means Command not supported.

P/S Sorry for my English)

Comment: AFAIK the APDU being complaint with PC/SC standard does not support it. However there are some readers that implements APDU that enables obtaining SAK and ATQA, as for instance some Springcard, etc. Besides, if you want to get the SAK and ATQA to define what type of card you are using, you can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967255/how-to-get-sak-to-identify-smart-card-type-using-java) where they explained it.